# Using LINQ intersect function with a non-primitive type

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using ENtity Framework with Code First. I have a list of objects that are being passed to a function, which will use the Intersect function from the DatabaseContext and pass the objects. It's not working. Here's the code:

```
public void BeginProcess(IEnumerable<Contract> selectedContracts)
    {

        DatabaseContext dc= new DatabaseContext();

        var contract = dc.Contracts.Intersect<Contract>(selectedContracts, new ContractComparer());


        foreach (var item in contract)
        {
            item.BatchNumber = 10;
        }
        //odc.Contracts.Intersect(selectedContracts).ToList().ForEach(x=>x.BatchNumber = batchNum);
        odc.SaveChanges();

    }
```

I created a ContractComparer class which implements IEqualityComparer:

```
public class ContractComparer : IEqualityComparer<Contract>
    {

        #region IEqualityComparer<Contract> Members

        public bool Equals(Contract x, Contract y)
        {
            //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

            //Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
                return false;

            return x.OID == y.OID;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Contract obj)
        {
            return base.GetHashCode();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

The error i get is:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Contract] Intersect[Contract](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Contract], System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Contract], System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1[Contract])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

How about;

```
var contract = dc.Contracts
    .Where(c => selectedContracts.Select(x => x.OID).ToList().Contains(c.OID));
```

Comment: This will only return a bool if the condition is satisfied, correct? I need to actually  modify the rows in the database, so I'll need a collection of the rows from the DatabaseContext that match the contracts in selectedContract

Comment: Ok, I've modified is slightly

Comment: And if `OID` is the Pk you can probably just write `dc.Contracts.Where(c => selectedContracts.Contains(c))`

Comment: I tried both ways and I'm getting the following error: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Contract'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context. Google's not helping much, any idea what this means?

Comment: ok.. try adding ToList() on the input collection `selectedContracts.Select(x => x.OID).ToList().Contains..` ?

Comment: Thank you Magnus for all your help. I decided to go another direction and used Dynamic LINQ to build a Where clause based on the selectedContracts OID (which is the primary key)

Answer (score 0):

Many poeple think that whatever they can do by linq-to-objects, can be done by linq-to-entities too - That's not correct. Prevalent examples are trying to use `.ToString()`, `.SubString()`, `.Intersect()`, etc.

To intersecting entity sets in L2E, you should use `.Contains()` method:

```
var contract = from c in db.Contracts
                       where selectedContracts.Contains(c.ContractID)
                       select c;
```